Remove files that were duplicated into sandboxes during Sonoma upgrade?
I've recently upgraded from Mojave (10.14) to Sonoma (14.5).
The Sonoma upgrade scanned through ~/Library and then copied various files into their new sandboxed locations in ~/Library/Containers or ~/Library/Group Containers. After the copy it seems to have left the original files behind in their old locations.
In particular, my old spelling dictionary is in ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary and there is also a copy in ~/Library/Group Containers/com.apple.AppleSpell/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary. These files aren't hardlinked or reflinked, they're independent copies.
I assume this happened with more than just the spelling dictionary.
Are the old files no longer needed (if not, why were they copied rather than moved?) Is there a way to identify which files got moved into sandboxes so I can delete the duplicates?
